# Protractor - If there is a presented element then do this else skip

Tags: selenium, protractor, mocha.js, chai

I have been trying to figure out what a way to eliminate testing that is not needed if a value is presented or not.

What I have created is that at this moment I have forced testing to always be passed due to the test I have done but I have now recognize that I need have a sort of IF-ELSE statement to speed up the testing since there will be 4 test cases which is not needed IF the value is not presented.

What I have done is:

```
//
//
// IF THIS IS TRUE THEN CONTINUE, ELSE WE SKIP TOTALLY
//

IF
    it('Clicking Next Step button', function (done) {

        browser.driver
            .then(() => utils.click(detailsSpecs.getNextStepButton()))
            .then(() => done());
    });

    //
    // Check if stock conflict
    //

    it('Checking stock conflict', function (done) {
        browser.driver
            .then(() => utils.presenceOf(detailsSpecs.getStockConflictMsg()))
            .then(() => done());
    });


    // Click Remove Button Button
    //

    it('Clicked all remove button', function (done) {

        let allBtns = detailsSpecs.getRemoveButtonDesktop();

        allBtns.count()
            .then(function (countElement) {

                console.log('Find buttons: ', countElement)

                for (let i = 0; i < countElement; i++) {
                    utils.click(detailsSpecs.getRemoveButtonDesktop().first())
                    browser.sleep(1000) // sleep 1s
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
                done();
            })

    });

    //
    // Click Next Step Button
    //

    it('Clicking Next Step button', function (done) {

        browser.driver
            .then(() => utils.elementToBeClickable(detailsSpecs.getNextStepButton()))
            .then(() => utils.click(detailsSpecs.getNextStepButton()))
            .then(() => done());
    });

ELSE
    SKIP
```

Basically what happens is, if the first test case is true (meaning there is a presented value) then we continue to do the rest, IF not then it will automatic be redirected to another page and here is what I have problems with... Because I have a standard timeout of 1 minute and that means that I will waste 4 minutes of testing due to the first testcase is not presented so I would like to skip the rest if the first testcase is not true.

My question is, what would be the best way to make a IF-ELSE statement to skip the test cases IF the first test case is not presented?

EDIT:

```
const stockConflictIsPresent = function (done) {
    return browser.driver
        .then(() => utils.presenceOf(detailsSpecs.getStockConflictMsg()))
        .then(() => done());
}


if (stockConflictIsPresent) {

    // Click Remove Button Button
    //

    it('Sleep', function (done) {

        setTimeout(function () {
            done();
        }, 5000);
    });

    it('Clicking Next Step button', function (done) {

        browser.driver
            .then(() => utils.elementToBeClickable(detailsSpecs.getNextStepButton()))
            .then(() => utils.click(detailsSpecs.getNextStepButton()))
            .then(() => done());
    });
} else {
    console.log("Done")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition in your if statement to check if your nextStepButton is present by:

```
const nextButtonIsPresent = function(done) {
  return browser.driver
        .then(() => detailsSpecs.getNextStepButton().isPresent())
        .then(() => done());
}

if (nextButtonIsPresent) {
  //... continue with the normal process here
} else {
  //... do your skip logic here
}
```

Comment: Is it possible if you can provide an example of how you mean because I am not quite sure of how you mean? I kinda do but not sure how to implement it the way you think?

Comment: So I have kinda done what you did, just that I didn't had any else statement due to I just want it to totally skip, Would that be fine? - Because it seems to still do the if statement even though it is not presented.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code I am using. It seems like it still goes into the if-statement even though the element for `utils.presenceOf(detailsSpecs.getStockConflictMsg())` is not there.

Answer (score -1):

we need to have more information about your first test case
u have to check with if statement of your element (or condition it depend on your case)

```
if(myElement.isPresent()){

    it('Clicking Next Step button', function (done) {

        browser.driver
            .then(() => utils.click(detailsSpecs.getNextStepButton()))
            .then(() => done());
    });

    //
    // Check if stock conflict
    //

    it('Checking stock conflict', function (done) {
        browser.driver
            .then(() => utils.presenceOf(detailsSpecs.getStockConflictMsg()))
            .then(() => done());
    });


    // Click Remove Button Button
    //

    it('Clicked all remove button', function (done) {

        let allBtns = detailsSpecs.getRemoveButtonDesktop();

        allBtns.count()
            .then(function (countElement) {

                console.log('Find buttons: ', countElement)

                for (let i = 0; i < countElement; i++) {
                    utils.click(detailsSpecs.getRemoveButtonDesktop().first())
                    browser.sleep(1000) // sleep 1s
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
                done();
            })

    });

    //
    // Click Next Step Button
    //

    it('Clicking Next Step button', function (done) {

        browser.driver
            .then(() => utils.elementToBeClickable(detailsSpecs.getNextStepButton()))
            .then(() => utils.click(detailsSpecs.getNextStepButton()))
            .then(() => done());
    });
}
else ...
```

Comment: I guess its almost same as above if I am correct? However I do have some issues if you check my question, I have edited a new code which maybe should explain abit more

Comment: basically the code that u already edited is what u looking for ?

Comment: Well the problem is that if still goes into the if-statement even though there isn't any presented in the "const" value.

Comment: utils.presenceOf(detailsSpecs.getStockConflictMsg()  this function check for a presence of an html element??

Comment: why do not use this myElement.isPresent() directly inside if statement

Comment: Hmm im not sure, I will try that (Btw I have no idea who downvoted you)

Comment: or try this : expect(elem.isDisplayed()).toBe(true); (i dont have any idea about downvote  hmmm)